# No interface word before interface Comparable

Tags: java, comparable

It is detail, but I want to know why this happens.

Exemplary code:

```
Class klasa = Enum.class;
for(Type t : klasa.getGenericInterfaces())
   System.out.println(t);
```

Output o the program:

```
java.lang.Comparable<E>
interface java.io.Serializable
```

Why on the output there is no interface word before `java.lang.Comparable<E>`. It is interface, yes?

In my opinion output should be:

```
**interface** java.lang.Comparable<E>
interface java.io.Serializable
```

Comparable is specially treated?

Comment: Lucky guess : Comparable is in the java.lang package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you get two different subclasses of `java.lang.reflect.Type`; one that is a generic type (probably `j.l.r.ParameterizedType`), and one that is a specific (non-generic) interface type (a `j.l.Class<?>`).

What do you want to do with that information, and why?

Comment: I want only to know why word `interface` is missing. This is `interface`, but `interface` word is missing.

Comment: Because two different versions of `toString()` are called; the Class<?> version that adds the interface, and the `ParameterizedType` subclass version that doesn't. Still, is this an academic question, or do you need to perform decisions based on that data?

Comment: This is academic question for my future knowledge.

Comment: If you have access to the OpenJDK sources, have a look into `java.lang.Class#toString()` and `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl#toString()`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`toString` method of `ParametrizedTypeImpl`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/reflect/generics/reflectiveObjects/ParameterizedTypeImpl.java.html#211)(the internal `Type` of `Comparable`), indicates that "interface" is not outputted in any case:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (ownerType != null) {
        if (ownerType instanceof Class)
            sb.append(((Class)ownerType).getName());
        else
            sb.append(ownerType.toString());

        sb.append(".");

        if (ownerType instanceof ParameterizedTypeImpl) {
            // Find simple name of nested type by removing the
            // shared prefix with owner.
            sb.append(rawType.getName().replace( ((ParameterizedTypeImpl)ownerType).rawType.getName() + "$",
                                     ""));
        } else
            sb.append(rawType.getName());
    } else
        sb.append(rawType.getName());

    if (actualTypeArguments != null &&
        actualTypeArguments.length > 0) {
        sb.append("<");
        boolean first = true;
        for(Type t: actualTypeArguments) {
            if (!first)
                sb.append(", ");
            if (t instanceof Class)
                sb.append(((Class)t).getName());
            else
                sb.append(t.toString());
            first = false;
        }
        sb.append(">");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

In the `toString` method of `Class`, on the other hand, "interface" is clearly output if the class is an interface.

```
public String toString() {
    return (isInterface() ? "interface " : (isPrimitive() ? "" : "class "))
        + getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[java.lang.Class#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

```
public String toString()
```

Converts the object to a string. The string representation is the string **"class" or "interface", followed by a space, and then by the fully qualified name of the class in the format returned by getName**. If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns the name of the primitive type. If this Class object represents void this method returns "void".

[sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl#toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/reflect/generics/reflectiveObjects/ParameterizedTypeImpl.java#ParameterizedTypeImpl.toString%28%29)

```
public String More ...toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (ownerType != null) {
        if (ownerType instanceof Class)
            sb.append(((Class)ownerType).getName());
        else
            sb.append(ownerType.toString());

        sb.append(".");

        if (ownerType instanceof ParameterizedTypeImpl) {
            // Find simple name of nested type by removing the
           // shared prefix with owner.
            sb.append(rawType.getName().replace( ((ParameterizedTypeImpl)ownerType).rawType.getName() + "$",
                                     ""));
        } else
            sb.append(rawType.getName());
    } else
        sb.append(rawType.getName());

    if (actualTypeArguments != null &&
        actualTypeArguments.length > 0) {
        sb.append("<");
        boolean first = true;
        for(Type t: actualTypeArguments) {
            if (!first)
                sb.append(", ");
            if (t instanceof Class)
                sb.append(((Class)t).getName());
            else
               sb.append(t.toString());
           first = false;
        }
        sb.append(">");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

After call to `toString()` method of `ParameterizedTypeImpl` does not append interface keyword. It just calls `getName()` method.

**The name `interface java.lang.Comparable` is there in t. After statement `System.out.println(t);` calls `toString()`.**
You can see below image, when I debug

[image]